# Using Highcharts formatter causes Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to display custom text in tooltip. When I use my code, I got `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when I hover on tooltip.

Does someone knows where's the problem?

```
tooltip: {
            shared: false,
            formatter: function() {
                var serie = this.series;
                var s = '<span style="color:' + serie.color + '">' + serie.options.name + '</span>: <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
                $.each(serie.options.composition, function(name, value) {//Error pop ups here
                    s += '<b>' + name + ':</b> ' + value + '<br>';
                });
                return s;
            }
        }
```

EDIT - Added error message:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedm.extend.each @ jquery.min.js:2$.highcharts.tooltip.formatter @ grafovi.php:823Mb.refresh @ highcharts.js:160Va.runPointActions @ highcharts.js:166Va.onContainerMouseMove @ highcharts.js:174Va.setDOMEvents.b.onmousemove @ highcharts.js:176
```

Comment: please copy/paste the error message

Comment: @lisztomania I copy/pasted error message

Comment: Check that `serie.options.composition` exists and is an array.

Comment: @Bolza Thank you for your suggestion. I checked if serie.options.composition is undefined and it solve my problem. You can post answer and I will mark it down as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for comment check that `serie.options.composition` exists and is an `array`.